# Create Dialog on publishing methods

Tags: development, joomla-3.4, custom-component, controller

I would like to create a little dialog on publishing-events on an item of my self-developed component.

For example: Item gets `published` - the item's controller is called and rund method `publish` with `$task` `publish`.

But now I would like to interrupt publishing-process: The user shall answer a question - for example:

Are you sure? `Yes (publish)` or `No (exit)`

This is the source of my controller so far:

```
/**
 * publish function.
 * 
 * @access public
 * @return void
 */
public function publish()
{
    $app                                    =   JFactory::getApplication();
    $jinput                                 =   JFactory::getApplication()->input;
    $ids                                    =   $jinput->get('cid', '', 'array');
    $task                                   =   $this->getTask();
    $date                                   =   JFactory::getDate();            
    $modelitem                              =   $this->getModel('Item');        

    foreach($ids as $id)
    {           
        switch($task)
        {
            case 'publish'  :                   // do stuff
                                                break;
            case 'unpublish':                   // do stuff
                                                break;
            case 'archive'  :                   // do stuff     
                                                break;
            case 'trash'    :                   // do stuff                                                 
                                                break;
        }

    }

    $publish                                =   $modelitem->publish($id, $state);

    $this->setRedirect('index.php?option=com_bestia&view=items', false);

    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way to implement a Confirmation dialog is on the client side, with Javascript routine. You can check how JToolbar does it:

```
    $bar = JToolbar::getInstance('toolbar');

    // Add a trash button.
    $bar->appendButton('Confirm', JText::_('COM_XXX_CONFIRM_PURGE'), 'trash', $alt, $task, $check, false);
```

In Javascript terms:

```
    if (confirm('....')){Joomla.submitbutton('....');}
```